# flex and initials with completion-styles

Tags: completion

I am using `completion-styles` and cannot decipher the difference between `flex` and `initials`.

Answer (score 1):

`initials` matches "acronyms and initialisms", e.g., can complete "M-x lch" to `list-command-history` and "C-x C-f ~/sew" can match "~/src/emacs/work".

`flex` will match an in-order subset of characters. When completing "foo" the glob "*f*o*o*" is used, so that "foo" can complete to "frodo".

You can read more about these and other options (like `basic` and `substring`) from the docstring for `completion-styles-alist`.

[Orderless](https://github.com/oantolin/orderless) and [Fussy](https://github.com/jojojames/fussy) are third-party packages to provide additional completion styles.

Answer (score 1):

See the manual:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `emacs-index-search` <kbd>RET</kbd> `completion-styles` <kbd>RET</kbd> takes you to `(emacs)Completion Styles`, which says:

```
‘flex’
     This aggressive completion style, also known as ‘flx’ or ‘fuzzy’ or
     ‘scatter’ completion, attempts to complete using in-order
     substrings.  For example, it can consider ‘foo’ to match ‘frodo’ or
     ‘fbarbazoo’.

‘initials’
     This very aggressive completion style attempts to complete acronyms
     and initialisms.  For example, when completing command names, it
     matches ‘lch’ to ‘list-command-history’.
```